# How to map model in asp.net mvc application with a mongodb collections

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

Hi I was trying to create an asp.net mvc application and thought of using mondoDb as database. A mongodb collection does not have any fixed schema to how do I map mongoDb collection in asp.net mvc model ?

I broswed a hell lot of website but could not find any related answer.

Anybody could you please enlighten me on this ?

And if I start with an enterprise level application do I need to use repository pattern and Dependency Injection in my application ? I tried to use these two but it sort of making my application complex.

I'm not puttin any code so please bear with me.

Please help me with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For mapping mongo collection on to your .Net types, you should use *strong typed collection* in *MongodDriver*. For example you have Person type:

```
Person {
  public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if you want to get all person from your mongo you should write like:

```
 var client = new MongoClient();
 var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
 var col = db.GetCollection<Person>("persons");
 var persons = col.Find(x => true).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get a MongoCollection ,you will get the repository:
var repo = db.GetCollection("ModelName");

now you can do query like :
repo.FindOne(Query.EQ(x => x.Id, id));
or 
repo.FindAll();
or
repo.Remove(..)
or 
repo.Update(..)

you can either create a common generic class as a repository or create for each mongo model class , depends on your business .

below is a sample model :

```
        class TestModel
        {
           public string Name {get;set;}

           [BsonIgnore]
           public string IgnoreThis{get;set;}

           [BsonId]
           [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
           public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

you can use [BsonId] and [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)] to use it as primary key for a collection.

below link listed some common attributes when mapping between c# model and mongodb collection . Hope helps.

http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.1/html/7c3829d2-ad42-6bbc-40c6-c2adca36078b.htm